# JSON to JSON Copy based on Keys

Tags: javascript, json, object, key, transform

So I have two json files, I want to go through one of them and match all the values from the second json file into the matching keys.

For example, suppose I have

```
var json1 = {val1: 1, val2:2, val3:3};
var json2 = {val1: 52, val2:56, val7: 7, val5: 5, val3:33};

parseandmatchjson(json1, json2) => {val1: 1, val2:2, val7: 7, val5: 5, val3:3};
```

So basically match all the keys in the first json to all the keys that also exist in the second json and replace the values.

Is there a library that does that? or if you can give me an example of how that can be done in javascript that would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
I should be more specific in that what I'm looking for is something that works when the structure is not necessarily the same,

For example

suppose I had

```
var json1 = {wrapper: 
    {val1: 1, val2: 2}
}
var json2 = {val1: 'without wrapper'}
```

can I still get something like with some library out there?

```
{wrapper: {val1: 'without wrapper', val2:2}}
```

Comment: Pretty much every library will merge two objects for you. `$.extend` in jQuery and `_.extend` in Underscore for starters.

Comment: That isn't JSON... those are just object literals.

Comment: is this a static literal object structure ? or it may be any structure ending with leaf key/values pairs called val1, val2 ... ?

Comment: @hthomos ... Answer updated based on your updated question, if it solves the issue, kindly mark it as answer

Comment: @Felix_Kling ... it's not a duplicate question BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using jquery , do it as follows:

```
function parseandmatchjson(json1, json2) {

    var combined_json = {};

    // Deep copy of json1 object literal
    for (var key in json1) {
        combined_json[key] = json1[key];
    }

    // Copy other values from json2
    for (var key in json2) {
        if (! json1.hasOwnProperty(key))
            combined_json[key] = json2[key];
    }

    return combined_json;
}

var json1 = {val1: 1, val2:2, val3:3};
var json2 = {val1: 52, val2:56, val7: 7, val5: 5, val3:33};
var json3 = parseandmatchjson(json1, json2);
```

if you are using jquery, it's simpler

```
var json1 = {val1: 1, val2:2, val3:3};
var json2 = {val1: 52, val2:56, val7: 7, val5: 5, val3:33};
var json3 = $.extend({}, json2, json1);
```

---

**EDIT**

**Based on PO's updated question, here is its updated solution to cover nested literals case**

FYA, In next solution, I'll assume that you don't use jQuery, as you didn't specify this in your question

```
function parseandmatchjson(json1, json2) {

    // private function to traverse json objects recursively
    function traverse(object, callback) {
        for (var key in object) {
            // only return leaf nodes
            if((/boolean|number|string/).test(typeof object[key]))
                callback.apply(this, [object, key, object[key]]);  
            // if not base condition, dig deeper in recursion
            if (object[key] !== null && typeof(object[key]) == "object")
                traverse(object[key], callback);
        }
    }

    // create deep clone copy of json1
    var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json1));

    // create a flattened version of json2 for doing optimized lookups
    var flat_json2 = {};
    traverse(json2, function(object, key,value) {
        flat_json2[key] = value;
    });

    // overwrite values in results, if they exist in json2
    traverse(result, function(object, key, value) {
        if(typeof flat_json2[key] !== "undefined" )
            object[key] =  flat_json2[key];
    });

    return result;    
}


// Now, lets test it
var json1 = {wrapper: {val1: 1, val2: 2}}
var json2 = {val1: 'without wrapper'}
var merged_json = parseandmatchjson(json1, json2); 

// check the result with a simple alert
alert(JSON.stringify(merged_json));
```

And here is a JSFiddle Sample [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2rdqsex/2/)

Comment: What is `$`? Assuming it's jQuery, why don't you just do `combined_json = $.extend({}, json2, json1);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was proposing a solution without jquery, but I forgot and implemented part of it with jquery, Corrected.

Comment: What if they aren't the same structure, suppose I had

{val-wrapper: {val1:1}}
and {val1: 52}

will doing $.extend({}, json2, json1) give me {val-wrapper:{val1: 52} ?

Comment: No, it will give you {"val1":52,"val_wrapper":{"val1":1}}

Comment: But you didn't specify this in your initial post :)

Comment: @hthomos, Answer updated based on your updated question. PS, if it solves your issue, kindly mark it as answer